# DOMDocument loadHTMLFile always returns false

Tags: php, domdocument

Following is the code, what I am missing here

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// this has file permission 644 previously, and changed to 755
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://gartneryrket.no/digitalemagasiner/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/1484716981/index.html');
// same code is working in another site 
// when I specify path not url then its working
```

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: it always return false @Thamaraiselvam, `var_dump($doc->loadHTMLFile(...))`  returns `bool(false)`

Comment: Use `file_get_contents` and `loadHTML`

Comment: It works on php 5.6. Usually suppressing error is not a good habit but suppressing in this case is accepted as the found codes are not yours.. use `libxml_use_internal_errors(false);` and `@doc->loadHTMLFile($url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use path like:

```
/home/gartneryrket/public_html/digitalemagasiner/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/1484716981/index.html
```

It works for me.